# Latex define Chinese font style for header

Tags: fonts, header, latex, styles, cjk

I am trying to a few include Chinese words in my document header, using the package `\usepackage{CJKutf8}`, the following gives me a pretty good Chinese font in text but I wasn't able to incorporate it into header:

> `\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gkai}数学\end{CJK*}`

The followings are in my `.cls` file to define my template, it only recognizes English letter input:

`\newfontfamily\headerfontChinese[   Path=\@fontdir,   UprightFont=*-Regular,   ItalicFont=*-Italic,   BoldFont=*-Bold,   BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic, ]{Roboto}`

`\newcommand*{\headerChinesesubtitlestyle}[1]{{\fontsize{20pt}
{1em}\headerfontChinese\color{gray}#1}}`

Is there any good way to adjust my `.cls` file to accept Chinese input to my header style? Thank you!

(p.s. I am compiling latex on Overleaf)
(p.s. In my fontdir there are a bunch of English template font)

Comment: Please provide a [mre] showing what you have tried so far. Note that the Roboto font does not support CJK.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use 楷书 in headings? I suggest you use `ctex` package, as it is already 2020

```latex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[UTF8]{article}

\usepackage{ctex}
\usepackage{zhlipsum}

\begin{document}

\title{\kaishu 数学}
\date{}
\author{\kaishu 作者}

\maketitle

\fangsong

\zhlipsum[6]

\end{document}
```

for more details, please check the `ctex` [documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/ctex).